# delete confirmation in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$result->my_id}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->province_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->city_name}}</td>
    <td>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('city-edit', $result->my_id)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{route('city-delete', $result->my_id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

How to add a confirmation on delete each data?

Comment: Just add `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"`. Check my post for a complete answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I prefer a more easier way, just add `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"`, as bellow:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="{{route('city-delete', $result->my_id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: Even if this code is shorter you should consider using event delegation and implement this action as [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: how to script it on " "?? is it "<a onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?')'> ??

Comment: You have used one pair of single quotations inside another one, which doesn't work. Please wrap a single pair quotation inside a double pair quotation or vise versa: 

`<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">` 
OR
 `<a onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?")'>`

Comment: Simple and effective. Fantastic. Remember kiddies, done is better than perfect :-)

Comment: how can i use sweet alert in this way??? this is the url of sweet alert. [link](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Answer (score 8):

If this is your link:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?">Delete</a>
```

Use this Javascript:

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
    deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

        if (choice) {
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** the `<a>` needs the `delete` in `class`.
This solution uses [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and should work with IE 9 or newer.

Answer (score 6):

```
  <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return myFunction();" href="{{route('city-delete', $result->my_id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      if(!confirm("Are You Sure to delete this"))
      event.preventDefault();
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: This action can be done unobtrusively with event delegation. Please stop using obtrusive Javascript and stop putting an `onclick` every where.

Comment: Thankyou for your info Peh.what happen if i use jquery selector using class .click event for the same process

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve the same with jquery too. But you should make sure to separate content and code, which is done by using the `data-confirm` attribute instead of hard coding the confirmation text into javascript.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="{{ route('city-delete', $result->my_id) }}" 
   class="btn btn-danger" data-method="DELETE" data-confirm="Are you sure?"> Delete</a>
```

With [`brexis/laravel-data-method`](https://github.com/brexis/laravel-data-method) package, you can specify appropriate HTTP method and a confirmation text.

This is helpful if you have this for example into your routes file:

```
Route::get('cities/{city}', 'CityController@show')->name('city-show');
Route::delete('cities/{city}', 'CityController@destroy')->name('city-delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your link:

```
<a href="{{route('venuepropertyarea.delete', ['propertyarea' => $propertyareaname->id])}}" data-method="DELETE" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/icrm/venues/property_area/delete/{propertyarea}', 'VenuePropertyAreaController@deletepropertyarea')->name('venuepropertyarea.delete');
```

Use this Javascript:

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
    deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

        if (choice) {
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** the `<a>` needs the `delete` in `class`.
This solution uses [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and should work with IE 9 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('todos.destroy', $todo->Id)}}" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
              @csrf
      <button id="btnDelete"class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
     </form>
<script type="javascript">
       document.onsubmit=function(){
           return confirm('Sure?');
       }
</script>
```

I used pure PHP Form, the method DELETE has to be passed as hidden on the submit page action, so I catch it trough javascript and I get the confirmation alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  class="btn btn-danger px-5  radius-30" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Unassign this agent?')" href="{{ route('unassign.agent', $report->id) }}" >Unassign</a>
```

the right route method